# dc.js barchart columns size is very small

Tags: dc.js

I have created one bar chart with dc.js javascript library. But bars are getting displayed very very small.

Even if we apply any filter on other dc.js controls it is displaying the bars only one under one horizontal line .

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: You generally need to share your code in order for people to figure out what might be going wrong. This problem usually occurs because the `xUnits` are wrong - dc.js uses `xUnits` to determine how many bars will be shown, and thus how wide the bars should be displayed. Generally `xUnits` will be related to how you define your bins in the group key function - here it looks like you're aggregating by day, so [`d3.timeDays`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#timeDay) is a likely guess.

Comment: I've added more detail to [the dc.js FAQ topic on this question](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-are-my-bars-one-pixel-wide).